# 2D-3D homography matrix estimation

Tags: image-processing, kinect, homography, camera-matrix

I am working with my Kinect on some 2D 3D image processing. Here is my problem: I have points in 3D (x,y,z) which lie on a plane. I also know the coordinates of the points on the RGB image (x,y). Now I want to estimate a 2D-3D homography matrix to estimate the (x1,y1,z1) coordinates to a random (x1,y1) point. I think that is possible, but I don't know where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is a [camera projection matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix), not a [homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography). A homography maps a plane seen from a camera to the same plane seen from another.

For estimating the camera matrix, look up solutions to solving for camera pose from known point correspondences. To get you started, [a seminal paper](https://icwww.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/lepetit_ijcv08.pdf) on the topic and the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) implementation [solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp).

Comment: the link to the paper was broken I believe.  Also if you know of any papers or tutorials to do this to map a 2D video frame of a TV broadcast tennis match to a 3D model of a tennis court or anything similar with regards to there being an environment and fast moving objects within it, please post them.